# Wrong table output for PLOS Computational Biology

Tags: tables, tabulary

Hello I am preparing a table for a publication on *PLOS Computational Biology* for which the template guidelines are in this [official link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/latex-template-for-plos-public-library-of-science-articles/tmfpqfxwdxbs). In order to replicate the problem I prepared a small example:

This is the **incorrect behavior**, notice the extra cells in the table vs the correct behavior. I tried to properly erase the number of cells I don;t need, but this causes an incorrect layout of the table.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.25in}{0in}
\centering
\caption{
{\bf Types of retrieved documents.}}
\begin{tabular}{|l+l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bf Type of document} & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bf Frequency} & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bf proportion (\%)}\\ \thickhline
$cell1 row1$ & cell2 row 1 & cell6 row 1 & cell7 row 1 & cell8 row 1\\ \hline
$cell1 row2$ & cell2 row 2 & cell3 row 2 & cell4 row 2 & cell5 row 2 & cell6 row 2 & cell7 row 2 & cell8 row 2\\ \hline
$cell1 row3$ & cell2 row 3 & cell3 row 3 & cell4 row 3 & cell5 row 3 & cell6 row 3 & cell7 row 3 & cell8 row 3\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{flushleft} Table notes Phasellus venenatis, tortor nec vestibulum mattis, massa tortor interdum felis, nec pellentesque metus tortor nec nisl. Ut ornare mauris tellus, vel dapibus arcu suscipit sed.
\end{flushleft}
\label{table1}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

Below is the **desired** result:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Types of retrieved documents}
\label{tab:values}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=2.0,
                table-space-text-post={\,\%}] 
                }
    \toprule Type of document        &   {Frequency} &   {Proportion (\%)}   \\
    \midrule
Journal                 &   1087         &   23\,\%          \\
Conference Proceeding   &   180         &   23\,\%          \\
Book series             &   115         &   23\,\%          \\
Book                    &   6           &   23\,\%          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I am not sure I understand what is going on. Any help in order to understand the problem and solve it for the next time would be welcome.

Comment: The template is very badly written and the space in comments is too small for listing all the errors it has. Start with loading `booktabs` and `siunitx`, but avoid `\makegapedcells` that doesn't work and also doesn't make for a better table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. On an IEEE publication the undesired behavior is actually correct. But when I transport it to the PLOS, it messes up all the layout and I have no idea how to better modifying it. Could you please give me a hand on how to properly modify it? Thanks if you can! :)

Comment: Not without a minimal example of a complete document.